# tcpkill for IPv6?

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6

How does one disable an IPv6 TCP connection?

It seems like it should be easy.  The only solution I found is a new effort that has a lot of potential, but needs to be developed further to be used as a de facto drop-in for tcpkill.

So, to clarify: how does one block IPv6 TCP connections with existing Debian packages?

---

In the interim, although I don't think it is the ideal solution, how do you disable IPv6 TCP connections entirely?

Answer (score -3):

To disable IPv6 permanently :

open editor with
`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Add the following at the bottom of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

In case to change it only temporarily use:

`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`

Replace 1 with 0 to enable it again

Comment: The OP is asking about terminating individual connections, not disabling the entire IPv6 stack.

Comment: Well, I guess I missed that. Sorry about that. Should I delete that answer?

Comment: @kanehekili hold on, let's salvage this post over time.  Do you mind un-deleting this, and I'll supplement with a follow-up.  Perhaps I can edit my question so that yours fits, for now.

Comment: @kanehekili I'll delete my answer where I copied over your content in a sec, didn't want to lose it, in case you delete it :)

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/when-or-should-you-delete-your-incorrect-answer) I shouldn't delete the question and I won't. It is off-topic but might help people in similar circumstances... @Christopher - you might remove the copy.